# scraping on dart, it appears 0 elements

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping

this is the dart code:

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> pklist = webScraper.getElement('div.d-flex > div > div > a',[]);
List<Map<String, dynamic>> compressedBalance = webScraper.getElement('span.js-balance-bitcoin > span',[]);
print(compressedBalance.toString());
```

it did works on the variable pklist but it didnt work on compressedBalance
the compressedBalance variable outputs an empty array like this []
but pklist variable output the elements

this is the element that im going to scrape:

```html
<span class="js-balance-bitcoin" data-address="15QN67y4vEZDZHFMwPGULfuYTGZ6HqCcR6">
    <span class="badge bg-light text-dark" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="Balance">
        <i class="cf cf-btc" aria-hidden="true" title="" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-original-title="BTC" aria-label="BTC"></i> 0
    </span>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="badge bg-light text-dark" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="Received">
        <i class="cf cf-btc" aria-hidden="true" title="" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-original-title="BTC" aria-label="BTC"></i> 0
    </span>
    &nbsp;<span class="badge bg-light text-dark" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="TX count"><i class="fas fa-sort"></i> 0</span>
</span>
```

btw pklist scraping elements is on another div, i dont include it here

Comment: Can you confirm that the HTML you posted includes all relevant parts of the document? I'm seeing the opposite of what you described: the query for compressedBalance matches 3 elements and pklist matches none, which seems correct as no part of the included HTML contains a div with class d-flex.

Comment: i only copy the span section, the one that is not working, the pklist is on another div

Comment: it seems like i have to wait for the elements to load, is there any solution for the program to wait untill it loads?